# Calling a "plus one" function from a view (link_to/button_to)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Let us say we have a piece of feedback that has a 'rank' column that keeps a total of votes. I want a link for each piece of feedback that will increment the rank column. Currently I am using this in the feedbacks view:

```
<%= link_to '+', action: rank_plus_one, id: feedback.id %>
```

and I have the following defined in FeedbacksHelper:

```
def rank_plus_one
    feedback = Feedback.find(params[:id])
    feedback.rank += 1
    feedback.save
    redirect_to feedbacks_path
end
```

I have researched around and found that this type of logic should indeed be placed as a controller helper method (correct me if I am wrong). However, I have tried a few various syntax's and found that none seemed to work correctly.

Comment: Oh, and the error says "Couldn't find Feedback without an ID"

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `feedback.id` as a parameter to your action.
(e.g.)

```
rank_plus_one(feedback.id)
```

Comment: If you'd like me to take a closer look in the next 30 min, click to my profile and connect with me on video chat.

Comment: henrymason, what would the link_to look like? Would I leave out the third param?